# Please reopen this question about ripping DVDs

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

[Ripping TV episodes from DVDs – how can I know which stream belongs to which episode?](https://superuser.com/questions/435413/ripping-tv-episodes-from-dvds-how-can-i-know-which-stream-belongs-to-which-epi)

I feel this question should be reopened. I can imagine it was closed in reaction to a flag by the first commenter, but we've all decided that any question regarding DRM is absolutely fine unless it's clearly about warez and whatnot.

I didn't even think about DRM or piracy issues here – is it the word "ripping" that suddenly makes all alarms go off?

The user didn't even *talk* about removing DRM from these media.

Please reopen this question. Even [Jeff says](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted/2215#2215):

> Unless it is a clear call for warez, discussion of DRM should be given the benefit of the doubt. […]
>
> Therefore, unless the post looks egregiously illegal, assume it is being asked in good faith about removing DRM on things you own, for your own fair use.

Comment: @nhinkle reopened... Cheers!

Comment: Alright, thanks @studiohack!

Answer (score 1):

The question has been reopened.