# Can I post a question about circumventing a registration code check?

Tags: discussion

I am a legitimate user of a piece of software called Creative Element Power Tools. It requires regular updating of the registration code but since Creative have withdrawn support, this is no longer possible and I am stuck with a non-functional application I often used.

I have a solution which involves rolling back the clock to the date it was originally installed and then set the clock back to today's date.

I would like to post but it could be considered a crack and therefore barred from this site.

Can I post this question on Super User or would it be considered inappropriate?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. CEPT is a collection of tools for which a new registration code had to be requested every so often. That is no longer possible. The solution to the problem is to roll back the clock to the date it was originally installed and then set the clock back to  today's date. It is cumbersome but a simple batch wrapper saves the day. But ... as I said, it could be considered a crack.  Legitimate, I feel, in this case.

Comment: Well, moderators aren't lawyers. We cannot enforce any EULA you agreed to when purchasing the software. If the EULA says you cannot use the software after it's being discontinued, it'd at least be considered *unethical* to crack it in order to keep using it. Then again, I can't find anything about this piece of software. It seems weird that they could just stop supporting it and leave users who have made a one-time payment with a non-functional application. Just like we deal with DRM questions, I'd say for personal use it should be fine.

Comment: My EULA says that I have indefinite use of the software on my one-time payment and it has not been discontinued. See http://www.creativelement.com/contact.html
I'm confident that my continued use is legal. That's not the point. My question is whether Superuser would accept it as a contribution.

Comment: In that case I don't see any issue with it. (Note: You can edit comments for up to five minutes after they've been posted. No need to delete and re-post.)

Comment: Thank you. Five minutes has often passed before one spots an error and then one can only delete and re-post. I have now posted the question we were talking about (with its answer).  I would have liked to refer to this conversation in meta but wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: " It seems weird that they could just stop supporting it and leave users who have made a one-time payment with a non-functional application. "  Happens everyday, why would think it's weird?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: If this is for your personal use of discontinued software, I'd say it's fine for Super User.

See also this old discussion about removal of DRM for personal purposes: [Is discussion of techniques for removing DRM permitted?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted)

Comment: Thanks. Very useful discussion.