# Can we or can we not discuss DRM removal?

Tags: discussion, support

I wanted to ask a question about removing DRM from content I own, so I researched the issue here on Meta. I came across [Is discussion of techniques for removing DRM permitted?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted) which seems to have a consensus that as long the question does not seem to be related to piracy, it should be given the benefit of the doubt.

With that in mind, I posted [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/856576/removing-drm-from-google-play-movies). It was put on hold, and as you can see in the comments, I referenced the above Meta question and asked what was wrong with my question. The moderator seemed to have a different interpretation than I did, and when I linked to a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/258608/how-can-i-remove-drm-from-kindle-books) about removing DRM, the moderator responded by putting that question on hold as well. If it was truly off topic, I imagine it would have been caught sometime earlier in the three and a half years since it's been asked.

To restate my question, are we or are we not allowed to discuss DRM removal on Super User? As the situation currently stands, it's not clear.

Answer (score 11):

I'd probably consider *intent* and that's what the question needs to reflect IMO.

Your *end* goal isn't DRM removal - in this case its trying to play the file in windows/and/or windows media player.

I'd consider the following points in this case

- Asking about how to *confirm* if this had DRM and what sort - this may simply be a broken or mislabeled file.
- Am I trying to *play* (which may need not need DRM removal,) or *backup* (which might)
- In short DRM removal should be part of a process related to fair use, rather than the end result.

Trying to work out how to *identify* and *play* such a file might make for a  much more useful question IMO.